# Will demoting a Windows Server 2003 Domain Controller reinstate local accounts?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, domain-controller, active-directory

We want to use our main DC to host an internal web application. After some testing and research, this application is failing because the machine doesn't have local accounts. We've decided to promote a different machine to our primary DC, and demote our current main DC.

Will the local accounts be recreated once we demote the machine?

Answer (score 2):

No, it ill not. It will recreate the standard accounts and set a new admin password, but it will not reinstate all other accounts that you may have had before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. *Random characters to meet the minimum character requirement.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you run dcpromo to demote the server, it will ask you to specify a password for the local administrator account.