# Restore accounts to undo dcpromo

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there any way to truly undo `dcpromo`? That is, a way that will restore all prior SAM accounts and passwords. Something less than a full drive backup?

A similar question ([Will demoting a Windows Server 2003 Domain Controller reinstate local accounts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/120915/will-demoting-a-windows-server-2003-domain-controller-reinstate-local-accounts)) asks if the demote command will automatically do this. This question asks if there is a way to pick up where it left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a one-way street. Once you've promoted you've overwritten the local security principles with new ones, and the same thing happens in reverse when you demote from Domain Controller. Windows does not keep an *oops* archive just in case you change your mind.

Comment: Is there any kind of System State backup/restore in `ntbackup` or Windows restore points that will do the trick?

Comment: @binarycoder Only if you took a System State Backup before running dcpromo in the first place. I don't believe one is automatically taken.